# BadImageFormatException - Is it possible to specify which .NET version is used to run an executable?

Tags: .net

I'm running a .NET 2.0 executable with a .com extension from a command line and receiving the following error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException : The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)
```

I'm pretty sure it's trying to load a DLL from the .NET 2.0 Global Assembly Cache.

I only get this error on machines with .net 4.0 / visual studio 2010 installed, so I'm assuming its using the wrong .net framework version to run.
Any ideas on how to confirm this assumption?

or is there a way to specify the program to use .net 2 runtime instead of .net 4 to run the .com file?

Comment: Did you rename the executable with the `.com` extension?

Comment: The .com executable is a third party assembly with a target runtime version of .net v2.0.50727.  But doesnt work on machines that have both .NET v2 and v4 (and v3.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the .NET 4.0 Framework is installed and you want to run an application build for/with .NET 2.0, you need to inform the .NET 4.0 Framework that the application requires the .NET 2.0 Runtime. That is done using a configuration file with the following entries.

The necessary attribute to set is the [useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
 </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - it's a third party application so I can't modify it.

Comment: @robbie. You don´t need to modify the application. Create a .config file for the executable and put the text above in the .config file.