# ASP.Net Web Pages v2.0 missing. Where to find it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-2

I have an ASP.Net MVC3 Project which references System.Web.Helpers v2.0 and System.Web.WebPages v2.0  These both come with MVC4 and is part of razor2.  However, my colleague doesn't have MVC4 installed, and doesn't have VS2012 installed, just vs2010 like myself. And his project compiles without the reference issue.
Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed: Version 10.0.40219.1. SP1Rel

I recently installed Windows 8 on a new PC but our project requires vs2010 and can't run on vs2012.
This project was working fine on another PC which had vs2012 installed.
The new PC has:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0 but not:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0

but my colleague has the latter folder and the v2.0 assemblies - without MVC4, and without vs2012 installed. How is this possible?

Comment: Install it from NuGet.

Comment: You do realize you don't need VS2012 to use MVC4, right?  You can install it in VS2010.  Just install it via the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes I realize this.  With respect, that is why I was saying that my colleague didn't have MVC4, was using vs2010, and yet these v2 assemblies were available.  I eventually found the solution, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this possible? -- 
After a lot of hit and miss, I found out that my colleague has [Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix).   This product when installed happens to implement razor v2 and installs the mentioned assemblies in the directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0

Answer (score 0):

Download it from here, use nuget console  :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/2.0.30506.0

Comment: Don't use the nugget version. It's not the same version and I have had problems with that one. One of the issues is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092435/system-methodaccessexception-attempt-by-security-transparent-method-to-access-s . That doesn't happens when you use the "Webmatrix" version