# Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method '

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

> Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.SiteAdmin.RegisterAdminModule()' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.ApplicationPart..ctor(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.String)' failed.

I am getting this error, quite often.
I am working on MVC5, .Net framework 4.5.
I build the solution, and run the application it runs fine.
I make some changes in code, build and then run the application, it runs fine.
Then again i change some code and run, it give me this error.

I cant figure out the reason, because it occurs randomly at any time.

I also googled, and found that change the web.config and edit the debug flag or edit some other config sections.

The problem is it runs for few times and then give this error.

I am using Windows 8, MVC version 5.1.0.0 dll

[Update]: Uploading screenshot of call stack.
[image: Error stack]

Comment: And what code are we talking about?

Comment: It doesn't seem specific to code. It occurs randomly.

Comment: What is the call stack?

Comment: The suggestions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092435/system-methodaccessexception-attempt-by-security-transparent-method-to-access-s?rq=1) didn't help?

Comment: Nope. Still the same... occurs randomly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926552/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-webmatrix-webdata-preapplicationstartcod)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, this question has had 638 views, and I am getting this same error but it is not intermittent.

Comment: "The delete extra files check box in the publish dialog solved it for me."
Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926552/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-webmatrix-webdata-preapplicationstartcod

Comment: Nope couldn't get it fixed so far i've already checked that link.